# stream and functional Interface: throw exception inside stream and aggregate them

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I am new to stream and functional interface and just wonder if this requirement could be done via them. Given an array of integers, if any of them is negative, then do not process but instead throw exception containing all negative integers.

```
Example: INPUT = [0, -1, -2] 
EXPECTED Exception: invalid integers: (-1, -2).
```

I do know how to do that with a for loop but really curious if this can be achieved via stream and functional interfaces. So any help is appreciated.

```
int [] input = {0, -1, -2};
List<Integer> negatives = new LinkedList<>();

for (int i : input) {
    if (i < 0) {
        negatives.add(i);
    }
}

if (negatives.isEmpty() == false) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid integers: " + negatives);
}
```

Comment: What kind of processing would you have to run on a valid stream? Can you post your `for` loop?

Comment: Share how you would do it with loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd write it with a simple `filter`:

```
final List<Integer> invalid = Arrays.asList(0, -1, -2).stream()
    .filter(i -> i < 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

if (!invalid.isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Invalid integers " + invalid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follow

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, -3, -2);
    checkList(list);
}

private static void checkList(List<Integer> list) {
    list.stream().filter(i -> i < 0).findFirst()
            .ifPresent(integer -> {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid are" + 
                             Arrays.toString(list.stream().filter(i -> i < 0).toArray()));
            });
}
```

Which will give

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid are[-3, -2]
```

Comment: you're iterating twice which is not ideal. What if the list has 1 billion elements and the only negative one is last?

Comment: @Michael sure, but don't see how do it in one row, in fully stream

Comment: Where was "do it in one row" a requirement? Why is doing it in one row - if it's less readable *and* less efficient - a good thing?

Comment: @Michael don't know^^ but apparently he accepted mine, but i agree yours is also very good, but I was looking for a way to not just collect and check